# Format String Attack?

Tags: c, security, printf

A recent security notice (http://osdir.com/ml/bugtraq.security/2015-04/msg00102.html) stated that this line of code:

```
fprintf(stderr, (isprint(adata->contents[i])) ? "%c " : "%02x", adata->contents[i]);
```

was subject to a "*format string attack*" which I understand as using something like:

```
fprintf(stderr, varWithUserSuppliedData);
```

instead of:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s", varWithUserSuppliedData);
```

but I'm not seeing that in that first fprintf call - what am I missing?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that fprintf call but I suspect that automatic program analysis tools could generate a false positive. But I'm not going to risk an answer yet :) Maybe someone will come up with a compelling argument as to why it is dangerous.

Comment: I've tried to see something that would be incorrect, however it all looks ok. I'm with you rici, I'll await a possible answer.

Comment: this has got to be a lame tool that say the word after stderr not starting with the character "

Comment: can you try char *a = "%s"; printf(a, " hi"); will this make false positive?

Comment: @pm100: I don't think that's the issue. It's rather that the used format string can be chosen by the user (maybe?), even though in this case it seems fine.

Comment: Could this be some issue with conversion to unsigned char (%c) or unsigned int (%02x) - I'm guessing here.... (poorly I think! :-))

Comment: I think the key words in the link are "prone to"... I think the claim is not that this is actually exploitable, but rather, that it's generally an insecure practice to allow untrusted data to influence a format string.

Comment: @Neil - same thought.  If `adata->contents[]` is `char` or `signed char`, hex output  is more than 2 digits.  Doubt that is a "format string attack".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @cremno for providing a link to the GIT repository for the file in question: [kssl.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/ssl/kssl.c#L970) (Note that this is *not* the repository head.)

It's clear that this report is spurious. First, there is no real problem with the `fprintf` call, although you can argue that code in a security-related product like OpenSSL needs to go beyond being secure to the point of being visibly secure even to a casual glance. (I'm not sure I would make that argument, but it has been made.)

But more importantly, the code in question is *disabled* (note the preprocessor directives surrounding it):

```
# if 0
{
    int i;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s[at%d:%d] ", label, adata->ad_type, adata->length);
    for (i = 0; i < adata->length; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, (isprint(adata->contents[i])) ? "%c " : "%02x",
                        adata->contents[i]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
# endif
```

Comment: Good to know my understanding of format string attacks remains viable! :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an automatically generated error message. Obviously the tool doesn't know which format string will be used, so it cannot analyse the format string and the arguments and declare that the usage is safe.

A more clever tool might figure out that there are just two possibilities for the format string, and that each possibility is safe, and not give an error message.

The code itself is safe. Of course you get rid of the message by using an if/else statement. And in safety critical code, you wouldn't just fix things that *are* wrong, but also things that *look* wrong. And you never know, after turning the fprintf into an if/else, the tool might detect a *real* problem that we all missed.

Answer (score 0):

Credit must go to rici, but everything looks ok with the code.

Even there is a problem, everything can be printed safe as char or as hex.

Probably the problem could be with the for or while loop that operates over the string.

Could you post the loop as well?

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2a/ssl/kssl.c#L955-L976 (note the purpose of the function is debugging and also the `#if 0`)

Comment: And I think the debug wouldn't be formatted that nicely! :-)